# Jquery Mobile List View on Blackberry torch

Tags: jquery, blackberry

For some reason my Blackberry Torch (OS 6.0 Bundle 2647) DOES NOT render listview in Jquery Mobile 1.1.1

Blackberry Bold works fine.

Any ideas if Listview and Persistent headers are supported in Blackberry Torch ?

Thanks

RG

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the listview?  Are you using the listfields?  The 9800 is at OS 6 level and 9900 is OS 7 level, so my suspect is that Jquery is using an API that is available on OS 7 and not in OS 6.

Thanks

Naveen M